# PrincipalSearcher Wrong Username Or Password error

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, principalsearcher

I'm trying to get user data from the active directory. Authentication process is true.

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "localhost-ad.local", "OU=LocalOu,DC=localhost-ad,DC=local", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
var login = context.ValidateCredentials("user.name", "password", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

But `PrincipalSearcher` returns a wrong username or password.

```
var user = new UserPrincipal(context);

var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();

List<UserPrincipal> results = new List<UserPrincipal>();

foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
{
    results.Add(p as UserPrincipal);
}

return results;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may stem from a misunderstanding of what `PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials` does.

It does not authenticate the context on the domain or allow access to the domain in any way, all it does is check if the username and password are correct and return `True` or `False`.

Instead you can authenticate with the domain as so:

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "localhost-ad.local",
    "OU=LocalOu,DC=localhost-ad,DC=local", "user.name", "password");
```